# Groovy - String each method

Tags: groovy

I have just started learning Groovy which looks really awesome!

This is very simple example.

```
"Groovy".each {a -> println a};
```

It nicely prints as given below.

```
G
r
o
o
v
y
```

My question is - 'each' method is not part of String object as per the link below. Then how come it works?

http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/

How can i get the parameters list for a closure of an object?

example String.each has 1 parameter, Map.each has 1 or 2 parameters like entry or key & value.

Comment: `each` in this case will be the method bound to `Object`

Comment: yes, i just noticed it..thanks :)

Comment: @tim_yates: I'm curious as well. The doc says it iterates through the items returned by the iterator() method. Where is the iterator() method, which iterates over the chars of the string, defined?

Comment: google for `DefaultGroovyMethods`

Comment: @injecteer I did, but I still coundn't find an iterator(String) method.

Comment: how about http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html

Comment: @JB Nizet, `iterator()` is also bound to `Object`. You should be looking for `iterator(Object)`, not `iterator(String)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant code in DefaultGroovyMethods is

```
public static Iterator iterator(Object o) {
   return DefaultTypeTransformation.asCollection(o).iterator();
}
```

which contains:

```
else if (value instanceof String) {
   return StringGroovyMethods.toList((String) value);
}
```

String toList is:

```
public static List<String> toList(String self) {
   int size = self.length();
   List<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>(size);
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      answer.add(self.substring(i, i + 1));
   }
   return answer;
}
```